# EF Fluent Api provides only .WithOne() but not .WithMany()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When I try to Map 2 tables with many to many relationship, I only get option .WithOne() but not getting .WithMany() ?
[image]

Here are those 2 classes.

```
public class Proizvod
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Naziv { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Racun> Racuni { get; set; }

    public Proizvod()
    {
        this.Racuni = new List<Racun>();
    }

}

    public class Racun
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<int> Kolicina { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Proizvod> Proizvodi { get; set; }

    public Racun()
    {
        this.Proizvodi = new List<Proizvod>();
        this.Kolicina = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but I'd recommend just creating the intermediate many-to-many join table RacunProizvod and entity.  This will mean each side is a one-to-many and you can join through this table to represent the many-to-many.  In my opinion this is more straightforward.

Comment: Well I will definitely try that. Thanks for comment @AaronLS